# How to implement Multiparallax Scrolling using Skrollr.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, skrollr

I'm having a bit of a problem with my understanding on how to implement the `skrollr.js`.

I just want to have the same effect as this one: The MULTI PARALLAX ONLY.

How do you implement something like this:

http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/

I tried using this one in CodePen but it doesn't scroll like the the example above.

HTML

```
<body style="height:1200px;">
    <div id="bg1" data-0="background-position:0px 0px;" data-end="background-position:-500px -10000px;" class="skrollable skrollable-between" style="background-position: 0px 0px;"></div>
    <div id="bg2" data-0="background-position:0px 0px;" data-end="background-position:-500px -10000px;" class="skrollable skrollable-between" style="background-position: 0px 0px;"></div>
    <div id="bg3" data-0="background-position:0px 0px;" data-end="background-position:-500px -10000px;" class="skrollable skrollable-between" style="background-position: 0px 0px;"></div>
</body>

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/dist/skrollr.min.js"></script>
```

CSS

```css
#bg1, #bg2, #bg3 {
    z-index: 50;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(https://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/examples/images/bubbles.png) repeat 0 0;
}

#bg2 {
    z-index: 49;
    background-image: url(https://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/examples/images/bubbles2.png);
}

#bg3 {
    z-index: 48;
    background-image: url(https://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/examples/images/bubbles3.png);
}

.skrollable {
    /*
     * First-level skrollables are positioned relative to window
     */
    position:fixed;

    /*
     * Skrollables by default have a z-index of 100 in order to make it easy to position elements in front/back without changing each skrollable
     */
    z-index:100;
}

.skrollr-mobile .skrollable {
    /*
     *  May cause issues on Android default browser (see #331 on GitHub).
     */
    position:absolute;
}

.skrollable .skrollable {
    /*
     * Second-level skrollables are positioned relative their parent skrollable
     */
    position:absolute;
}

.skrollable .skrollable .skrollable {
    /*
     * Third-level (and below) skrollables are positioned static
     */
    position:static;
}
```

JS

```js
(function($){

     skrollr.init();

})(jQuery);
```

Hoping you could enlighten me. I'm still noob though.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the parallax effect you want but **[here](https://ihatetomatoes.net/skrollr-cheatsheet/)** is something that can help you to work around and play with it.

Also I have updated your code and made a demo of multiparallax scrolling by using `data-100-start` and `data-100-end` attributes.

```
<div id="bg1" data-100-start="background-position:0px 0px;" data-100-end="background-position:-500px -10000px;" class="skrollable skrollable-between" style="background-position: 0px 0px;"></div>
<div id="bg2" data-100-start="background-position:0px 0px;" data-100-end="background-position:-500px -10000px;" class="skrollable skrollable-between" style="background-position: 0px 0px;"></div>
<div id="bg3" data-100-start="background-position:0px 0px;" data-100-end="background-position:-500px -10000px;" class="skrollable skrollable-between" style="background-position: 0px 0px;"></div>
```

Please refer this [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ktzepu1t/2/).

Comment: it's close to the effect that i want but there's no transition between the background images somewhat a smooth easing transistion. do you know how?

Comment: You can add css transitions. I didn't find any data attribute for changing speed in skrollr. So I added transitions. Please refer this - https://jsfiddle.net/ktzepu1t/4/